# How to count all stored procedures in the SQL Server for a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I count all stored procedures which are written by me in my database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query to list SQL Server stored procedures along with lines of code for each procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291574/query-to-list-sql-server-stored-procedures-along-with-lines-of-code-for-each-proc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the OP pointed out in a comment, **all** of the earlier answers are wrong, because they include **system** procedures. He specifically asked for procedures that were "written by me" -- and later clarified in another comment "*other than the system procedure, written by me or anybody working on that data base*."

So to exclude system procedures, the only differentiating field I see in sys.procedures is the name. Therefore you need to add a WHERE clause to any of the other answers, like this:

```
select count(*) from sys.procedures
where name not like 'sp_%'
```

Comment: SELECT count(*) FROM sys.procedures WHERE SUBSTRING([name], 1, 3) <> 'sp_' for SQL 2019, SSMS 19

Comment: OR add a backslash before the underscore

Answer (score 50):

```
select Count(*) from sys.procedures
```

And as Philip Kelley noted this is sql 2005 and up

Answer (score 16):

```
-- Information about table -- 
SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U'

-- Information about Stored Procedure --
SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'P'

-- Information about Functions --
SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'FN'

-- Information about Views --
SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'V'
```

Answer (score 10):

To get the Stored Procedure count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) SPCOUNT 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
 WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

or:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM sys.procedures
```

or:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM sys.sysobjects
 WHERE xtype = 'P'
```

Hope one of these help.

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(name)
from sys.objects
where type = 'P'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Comment: This gives a count including both system and mine written stored procedure, i want to know count for my own written stored procedure only.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet: That's not what your question asked.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet When you say "mine written", are you talking about the procedures written only by your user?, or any user?

Comment: other then the system procedure, witten by me or any body working on that data base

Comment: This now is a duplicate question

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*)
from sysobjects
where xtype='P'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the count of tables and stored procedures.

```
SELECT 
    CASE TYPE 
        WHEN 'U' 
            THEN 'User Defined Tables' 
        WHEN 'S'
            THEN 'System Tables'
        WHEN 'IT'
            THEN 'Internal Tables'
        WHEN 'P'
            THEN 'Stored Procedures'
        WHEN 'PC'
            THEN 'CLR Stored Procedures'
        WHEN 'X'
            THEN 'Extended Stored Procedures'
    END, 
    COUNT(*)     
FROM SYS.OBJECTS
WHERE TYPE IN ('U', 'P', 'PC', 'S', 'IT', 'X')
GROUP BY TYPE
```

You can find in `sys.objects` all types of objects in the database. You will have to run this query on each of your databases to see the count of objects.